# Android Q, Touch screen does not scale after resolution changed

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to change the resolution from 720x1280 to 1080X1920 by this command.

## wm size 1080X1920

However, the resolution changed and looked very well, but the touch screen doesn't.
The touch region remains in 720x1280, a part of the area in desktop has no event response when I am touching it.

Does anyone know what the rule changes in AOSP from Android O to Android Q?
I am trying to find out the problem in WindowManager.java but got no root cause still.
Any information would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target surface touch range of the input event at isPointInsideSurface which is described in InputReader.cpp.
It reports the wrong input event coordinate after resolution scaled.

## Change the rule back to the old version, problem resolved.

```
bool TouchInputMapper::isPointInsideSurface(int32_t x, int32_t y) {
const float scaledX = x * mXScale;
const float scaledY = y * mYScale;
return x >= mRawPointerAxes.x.minValue && x <= mRawPointerAxes.x.maxValue
        && scaledX >= mPhysicalLeft && scaledX <= mPhysicalLeft + mPhysicalWidth
        && y >= mRawPointerAxes.y.minValue && y <= mRawPointerAxes.y.maxValue
        && scaledY >= mPhysicalTop && scaledY <= mPhysicalTop + mPhysicalHeight;
```

## change to:

```
return x >= mRawPointerAxes.x.minValue && x <= mRawPointerAxes.x.maxValue && y >= mRawPointerAxes.y.minValue && y <= mRawPointerAxes.y.maxValue;
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my AOSP10 device! Is there a corresponding Android bug ticket?